# What does suffix -dem mean?

Tags: pronouns, suffixes

Keller's Learn to Read Latin says:

> The adjective *Idem, eadem, idem* is formed by the addition of the suffix *-dem* to the demonstrative adjective *is, ea, id*.

What does suffix *-dem* mean? I couldn't find it in the Oxford Latin Dictionary.

Comment: @Joonas why did you tag my post with pronouns? They are adjectives, mentioned in the quote.

Comment: I would say that both *idem* and *is* are pronouns. The boundary between the two concepts isn't always clear, and there are different conventions. Feel free to add a tag for adjectives if you think that is a more apt name, but do keep the pronoun tag as many will see those words as pronouns.

Answer (score 3):

In practice it means nothing.
What I mean by this is that the suffix *-dem* has only very special uses, you cannot use it productively on new words, and it does not have an easily predictable effect on the meaning.
It is therefore practical not to treat *-dem* as a suffix, apart from remembering how to inflect the pronoun *idem*.
It therefore makes perfect sense for the suffix not to appear in dictionaries.

The etymology of the suffix *-dem* and whether it is a misinterpretation of an actual suffix *-em* as mentioned by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-dem#Latin) I will leave to others.
That is interesting, but not very relevant for learning to use Latin.

Comment: Thanks. I can't visit Wiktionary, due to the Great Firewall. Could you copy and paste here  from Wiktionary? I can't see screenshot hosted on imgur either, because imgur is blocked.

Comment: @Tim Wiktionary says: "Misinterpretation of *-em*. When the old ablative cases of *is, eōd, eād*, became *eō, eā*, the true forms *eōd-em, eād-em* were interpreted as *eō-dem, eā-dem*. The neuter nominative singular *id-em* is natural and gives earlier *emem* (= later *eundem*). The new marker *-dem* then served to create *totidem, tantumdem, ibīdem*, etc. Compare *tam-en* with its later doublet: *tan-dem* (← *_tam-dem_)." But as I said, whether that is a good description should be explained someone more etymologically qualified than me.